# how to solve git merge "file to long" error

Tags: github

I'm trying to merge master into one branch, but I'm getting this error from github:

```
Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: Unable to create 'C:/Users/me/Documents/code/comp/myproject/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/very_long_branch_name': Filename too long
fatal: failed to run reflog
error: task 'gc' failed
```

I get the same error when attempting to run `pull` from the command line, but I can do it using VSC git plugin. I think the issue is related to some branch that was merged in the past.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the big file.

```
git rm <filename>
```

and you're good to go!

Comment: It says that <filename> did not match any name

Comment: Try renaming your branch to a shorter one.

Comment: The problem is that that branch doesn't exist anymore, it was already deleted, but some history remains that raises this error when merging or pulling

Comment: git remote prune origin
git fetch --prune
git reset --hard origin/your_branch_name
git pull origin your_branch_name
git gc
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master

Before doing above commands, make sure you have backup of the data.